# Keras accuracy discrepancy in fine-tuned model

Tags: keras

## Background

While fine tuning a classification model in Keras, it printed `val_acc: 0.8456`. [This code](https://pythonexample.com/snippet/python/transfer_learning_keras_01py_gengho_python) was used for fine-tuning.

After fine-tuning, manually loading the trained model and predicting the valuation set, a much lower accuracy of `0.28` was received.

The following code was used for valuation:

```
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
...
img = kimage.load_img(img_path, target_size=target_size)
x = kimage.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = vgg19.preprocess_input(x)
pred = model.predict(x)
```

## Question

What might be the cause for the big discrepancy in accuracy `0.85 != 0.28`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using different preprocessing for training and testing.
Specifically,

```
rescale = 1./255
```

is used for training, but

```
x = vgg19.preprocess_input(x)
```

is used for testing.

What `imagenet_utils.preprocess_input()` does is subtracting the mean (computed on ImageNet, as suggested by the name):

```
    # Zero-center by mean pixel
    x[:, :, :, 0] -= 103.939
    x[:, :, :, 1] -= 116.779
    x[:, :, :, 2] -= 123.68
```

So it's fairly different from the preprocessing applied on your training data.

Answer (score 1):

## Using the same `ImageDataGenerator`

My `ImageDataGenerator` was:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255, ...)
```

Was able to reproduce its preprocessing as follows:

```
img = load_img(image_path, target_size=target_size)
x = img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x *= rescale_factor

score = model.predict(x)
```